# After fetching data: new state is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

I'm successfully fetching data. The data I'm getting back looks like this:

```
{message: "Success", savedAnswer {Question1: "Yes", Question2: "Yes"}}
```

The problem: When I'm trying to update the state I get a state of "undefined" in my console.

Here is my code:

```js
const [redirectOnLogin, setRedirectOnLogin] = useState(false);
const [loginLoading, setLoginLoading] = useState(false);
const [userAnswer, setUserAnswer] = useState([]);


const submitAnswers = async (answers) => {
    try {
      setLoginLoading(true);
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        `signupQuestions`,
        answers
      );   
  
      console.log(data.savedAnswer) //works properly
      setUserAnswer(data.savedAnswer);  
      console.log(userAnswer) //undefined

      setTimeout(() => {
        setRedirectOnLogin(true);
      }, 700);
    } catch (error) {
      setLoginLoading(false);
      const { data } = error.response;
    }
  };
```

When I console.log(data) everything works (see code), but when I update the state and console.log(userAnswer) I get "undefined".

I think this has something to do with rendering? I already tried to add conditions in the code, like:

```
if (data.savedAnswer !== undefined) {
setUserAnswer(data.savedAnswer)
}
```

..but I can't get it work. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setUserAnswer` is the asynchronous method and you can't get the updated value of `userAnswer` immediately after `setUserAnswer()`.

```
setUserAnswer(data.savedAnswer);  
console.log(userAnswer) //This will console old value of `userAnswer`
```

You should use `useEffect` with adding a `userAnswer` as a dependency to useEffect hook. This will console.log the userAnswer value every time its updated.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(userAnswer);
}, [userAnswer]);
```

[Refer react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value) for setState.

Comment: Thank you. The code works - I tried something similar, but I used useEffect incorrectly..this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Each render has its own values for the state variables(created using useState).

Calling setUserAnswer triggers a new render with the new value, and in the new render the new value is available (returned by useState), but in the original render the variable remains unchanged.

Internally react compares the references of the state from the original and the next render to determine if anything changed (for instance when you pass the variable to the useEffect dependency array).

The code provided by William Wang's answer will work because the next render will find that the values passed into useEffect dependencies array are different and will execute the console.log in the scope of the next render.

see [this blog post from Dan Abramov](https://iqkui.com/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-props-and-state) that explains what I just said

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and the link. This is very helpful!